# How can I null some property of an object using microsoft graph API - when only PATCH requests are allowed?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I don't know how to use Microsoft Graph API to remove some existing property of an object. For example if I created a User object with property "department" and I want to set this to null now (but applies also to any other optional property), I cannot do this using the PATCH request offered, because PATCH ignores nulled values. What should I do?

I understand that with some fields you can use empty `String` value to overcome this problem, but sometimes it is not possible due to checks on this field..

I am using version 1.0 of the Graph API, testing on request

```
PATCH /v1.0/users/{id}
Content-type: application/json
with json body:
{
  "givenName": "testUser",
  "surname": "test",
  "department": "department value"
}
```

Comment: I am facing a similar issue with Microsoft's own Java API. Did you manage to configure Jackson to include those null values?

Answer (score 1):

If the property is nullable, you can set it to `null`:

```
PATCH /v1.0/users/{id}
Content-type: application/json
with json body:
{
  "givenName": "testUser",
  "surname": "test",
  "department": null
}
```

Comment: Sorry for stupid question, I was sure that the problem is that the PATCH request ignores null values, but I can see that the problem is that I am calling the API from Java using Jackson encoder, I think the problem will be in the encoder settings then, that it excludes the property in the call completely if its null. I tried calling the API directly and it works as you wrote. Sorry.

Comment: There are no stupid questions. Or very few, at least.